# How does Doomfist's "The Best Defense" Passive work?

Tags: overwatch

With the release of Doomfist on the PTR I have been trying him out to see how he plays and where he might fit on a team. However the information describing how his abilities and passive works is rather vague. In particular I am wonder how his passive "The Best Defense" works, it reads:

> **THE BEST DEFENSE...**
>
> Doomfist generates temporary personal shields when he deals ability damage.

I am wondering if the shield generated is a flat amount determined by the ability used, or if it is an amount determined by how much damage is done?

A lot of his abilities can hit multiple Heros at a time, so I am also wondering if he gets more shields for hitting multiple people, or if it is capped at one hero hit.

Comment: @downvoter could you leave a comment so that I might improve the question?

Comment: I would imagine that someone, somehow, thinks Doomfist hasn't been released yet, and has downvoted based on our "no questions about unreleased content" rule.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would imagine that someone thinks this question "does not show any research effort; is unclear or not useful". But that's just a hunch I have.

Comment: Ah, well does PTR count as unreleased? Going by past hero release experience, Blizz doesn't really change the new Heros game play wise between PTR and Live. It seems to be more about finding bugs and such rather than balance.

Comment: No, that's not usually the case. Playable on the PTR is grounds for acceptable questions.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If you have a problem with me, I'd suggest you take it somewhere private.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No, why do you ask? Trying to guess people's reasons for downvoting is futile, as there already is a given reason for every downvote. Furthermore, downvotes are by their nature anonymous and are not required to provide a reason, and unreleased content would be met with a close vote or a flag, not a downvote. Brushing downvotes aside because you assume the downvoter must be mistaken in their reasoning is not helpful to anybody.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer As much as I understand that downvotes are anonymous and they aren't obligated to reply, I figure there is no harm in asking if it means on the off chance they do reply that I can improve the question.

Comment: Ask yourself this: is your question easy to find out by yourself, whether by looking up resources online or by playing the game? Is your question about a case so specific that nobody else could benefit from the answer? I guarantee this'll be more effective than asking downvoters for their reasons.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I wouldn't consider this to be easily testable by yourself. To find out if it is damage based would require a second player on a damage boosting hero and testing with you. Based on how new the hero is I also wouldn't expect there to have been thorough testing already done and posted online yet.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill It's ridiculously easy to test in five minutes in the Practice Range. You do not need damage boosts to test this. And as a matter of fact, there's *plenty* of testing already done everywhere on YouTube. New heroes bring in views, so everyone's already jumped on that. That's how I answered the question, if you were curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each enemy hit by Doomfist's abilities (including Rocket Punch) generates 30 shields if hit by a regular ability, and 75 if hit by Meteor Strike, up to a maximum of 150 extra shields. The amount of shields generated does not depend on how much damage Doomfist deals with his abilities.

These shields are temporary and will disappear when damaged; starting one second after they were gained, they will start decaying at a rate of 3 shields per second.

Comment: A few things folks. First, please avoid extended discussion in comments. Second, if you really feel that an answer is incomplete without some information you're always free to post your own answer. Third, answers which add in new information are not duplicate answers. Fourth, [be nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).